# Sulu CMS: is it possible to restrict the creation of nodes of a certain type only under nodes of another particular type?

Tags: sulu

We are in a situation where we have pages of the `news` template type, that can carry any number of nodes of the `news_item` template type. In effect they should *only ever carry nodes of that type and that type alone*, and nodes of the `news_item` type *should only be created under nodes of the `news` type*. Thus, the "available templates" for a user when he/she tries to create new content under a `news` node should only be a `news_item`.

Is it possible to enforce this somewhere? For instance as some kind of attribute in the `news_item` and `news` xml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that's not possible. There is [quite an old issue on github](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/issues/913) describing that, but it had never  a high enough priority for us to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)